# Как корректно прописать if else в данном коде

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Подскажите как в функции breakWay5() в данном коде корректно задать if, else чтобы сравнивало результат формулы в данной функции с введённым значением vaf?

```js
let resultRct;
let resultVct;
let resultVct1;
let resultVct2;
let resultVct3;
let resultFi1;
let resultFi2;
let resultFi3;
let resultFi4;
function getGlobal1() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#JGlobal1').querySelector('input').value)
}
let Fi = getGlobal1();
document.querySelector('#JGlobal1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    Fi = getGlobal1();

})
function getGlobal2() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#JGlobal2').querySelector('input').value)
}
let Fi2 = getGlobal1();
document.querySelector('#JGlobal2').addEventListener('change', function() {
    Fi2 = getGlobal1();

})

function getGlobalVaf() {
    return Number(document.querySelector('#VafGlobal').querySelector('input').value)
}
let Vaf = getGlobalVaf();
document.querySelector('#VafGlobal').addEventListener('change', function() {
    Vaf = getGlobalVaf();

})

function breakWay2() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInput2');
    const h = +form[0].value;
    const S = +form[1].value;
    resultRct = ((S ** 2) + (4 * (h ** 2))) / (8 * h) ;
    console.log(+resultRct.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF3');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultRct.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultRct.toFixed(2);
}

function breakWay3() {
    resultFi1 = 0.8 * Fi;
    console.log(+resultFi1.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF4');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultFi1.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultFi1.toFixed(2);
}

function breakWay33() {
    resultFi2 = 0.8 * Fi2;
    console.log(+resultFi2.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF44');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultFi2.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultFi2.toFixed(2);
}

function breakWay4() {
    resultFi3 = 0.9 * Fi;
    console.log(+resultFi3.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF5');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultFi3.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultFi3.toFixed(2);
}

function breakWay44() {
    resultFi4 = 0.9 * Fi2;
    console.log(+resultFi4.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF55');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultFi4.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultFi4.toFixed(2);
}

function breakWay5() {
     resultVct = Math.sqrt(127 * resultRct * resultFi1);
     console.log(+resultVct.toFixed(1));
     const result = document.querySelector('#resultF6');
     result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultVct.toFixed(1))}`;
     return +resultVct.toFixed(1);
    
     const div = document.getElementById("resultVaf");

    if (resultVct > Vaf) {
        div.innerText = 'Скорость превышает'
    } else {
        div.innerText = 'Скорость не превышает'

    }


}

function breakWay6() {
    resultVct1 = Math.sqrt(127 * resultRct * resultFi2) ;
    console.log(+resultVct1.toFixed(1));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF7');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultVct1.toFixed(1))}`;
    return +resultVct1.toFixed(1);
}

function breakWay7() {
    resultVct2 = Math.sqrt(127 * resultRct * resultFi3) ;
    console.log(+resultVct2.toFixed(1));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF8');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultVct2.toFixed(1))}`;
    return +resultVct2.toFixed(1);
}

function breakWay8() {
    resultVct3 = Math.sqrt(127 * resultRct * resultFi4) ;
    console.log(+resultVct3.toFixed(1));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF9');
    result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultVct3.toFixed(1))}`;
    return +resultVct3.toFixed(1);
}

function startAll() { breakWay2(); breakWay3(); breakWay33();  breakWay4(); breakWay44(); breakWay5(); breakWay6(); breakWay7(); breakWay8();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Заокругление</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Граничная скорость</h1>

<form id="formInput2">
    <div>
        <label>h</label>
        <input type="number" value = 0.12>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>S</label>
        <input type="number" value = 10>
    </div>
</form>

<form id="VafGlobal">
    <div>
        <label>Vaf</label>
        <input type="number">
    </div>
</form>

<button onclick="breakWay2()">Результат Rцт</button>
<h2 id="resultF3"></h2>

<div id="global-Fi"></div>
<div id="global-Fi2"></div>

<form id="JGlobal1">
    <div>
        <label>φ</label>
        <input type="number" value = 0.4>
    </div>
</form>
<form id="JGlobal2">
    <div>
        <label>φ</label>
        <input type="number" value = 0.6>
    </div>
</form>

<button onclick="startAll()">Результат Общий</button>
<h2 id="startAll"></h2>

<table border="1">

    <caption>Таблица</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Номер варианта</th>
        <th>φ`</th>
        <th>Vцт, км/ч</th>
        <th>Сравнение</th>

    </tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><h2 id="resultF4"></h2></td><td><h2 id="resultF6"></h2></td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><h2 id="resultF44"></h2></td><td><h2 id="resultF7"></h2></td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td><h2 id="resultF5"></h2></td><td><h2 id="resultF8"></h2></td><td>.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td><h2 id="resultF55"></h2></td><td><h2 id="resultF9"></h2></td><td>.</td></tr>
</table>

<h2 id="resultVaf"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит корректно? У вас, визуально, вроде как корректно написано

Comment: @Swad, по факту оно не работает от слова "совсем"( Должно под таблицей выводить текст из условия и корректно работать, а не происходит ничего

Comment: И правильно не работает. Как оно будет работать, если функция заканчивается раньше на команде `return +resultVct.toFixed(1);`, но сам if написан правильно

Comment: @SwaD, получается эту строку, что Вы указали надо убрать и будет работать?

Comment: Если вы ее просто уберете, фукнция перестанет возвращать результат. Надо просто перенести return в конец функции

Comment: @SwaD, ещё вопрос - как мне дублировать вывод значений из таблицы под формулу? Например в <h2 id="resultF4"></h2> как-то сделать <h2 id="resultF4_2"></h2> только как это реализовать по-людски

Comment: Сначала сделайте, что бы работало как надо, позже займетесь оптимизацией кода. Как по мне, все ваши функций можно объеденить в одну. Поэтому пока просто продублируйте вывод в вашей ` breakWay3`

Comment: @SwaD, я пока решил так оставить чтобы другие формулы понаписывать, я сделал скрипт чисто техничку - common.js, туда пихаю всё глобальное типа селекторов с важными значениями и тд, поэтому и решил спросить на этом этапе эту вещь потому что как раз столкнулся с этим

Comment: Вот так сходу, я бы `getGlobal1` и `getGlobal2` объединил в одну. Думаю из остальных так же можно попробовать сделать универсальные функции, в которые надо передавать параметры для расчета. Ну и конечно все это надо смотреть исходя из ваших задач и применимости

Comment: @SwaD, ну я пока решил сделать так, мне так проще потом будет, потому что может что-то придётся поправить и так будет легче на данном этапе. Просто дошёл вот до таблиц и немного стопорнулся  с выводом этим дублированным(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо **return** перенести в конец фукнции:

```
function breakWay5() {
     resultVct = Math.sqrt(127 * resultRct * resultFi1);
     console.log(+resultVct.toFixed(1));
     const result = document.querySelector('#resultF6');
     result.innerText = ` ${Number(resultVct.toFixed(1))}`;         
    
     const div = document.getElementById("resultVaf");

    if (resultVct > Vaf) {
        div.innerText = 'Скорость превышает'
    } else {
        div.innerText = 'Скорость не превышает'
    }
    // Переносим return в конец функции
    return +resultVct.toFixed(1);
}
```

> **return** прекращает работу фукнции и возвращает результат

Comment: спасибо, работает) (извините что надоедаю своими вопросами через день))